# How to search in an List and my List is look like : List<Object> myList = new ArrayList<Object>()

Tags: list, search, arraylist, java-6

I want to search in a List and my List is look like

```
List<Employee> oneEmp= new ArrayList<Employee>();
List<Employee> twoEmp= new ArrayList<Employee>();



oneEmp= [Employee [eid=1001, eName=Sam Smith, eAddress=Bangluru, eSalary=10000000], Employee [eid=0, eName=, eAddress=, eSalary=null], Employee [eid=1003, eName=Amt Lime, eAddress=G Bhagyoday, eSalary=200000], Employee [eid=1004, eName=Ash Wake, eAddress=BMC, eSalary=200000], Employee [eid=1005, eName=Will Smith, eAddress= Delhi, eSalary=200000], Employee [eid=1006, eName=Shya Ymwar, eAddress=Madras, eSalary=50000], Employee [eid=1007, eName=Nag Gam, eAddress=Pune, eSalary=10000000], Employee [eid=1008, eName=Arti, eAddress=Delhi, eSalary=10000000]]

twoEmp= [Employee [eid=0, eName=null, eAddress=null, eSalary=100000], Employee [eid=0, eName=null, eAddress=null, eSalary=50000], Employee [eid=0, eName=null, eAddress=null, eSalary=200000]]
```

I am using code like this:-

```
for(Employee two : twoEmp){
        for (Iterator<Employee> iterator = oneEmp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
        Employee e = iterator.next();
        if (e.geteSalary() != null && two.geteSalary() != null && e.geteSalary().compareTo(two.geteSalary()) == 0) {
            finalEmpList.add(e);
        }
        }
    }
```

But this still required 2 for loop

> I am using JAVA 1.6

My Employee class has attributes:

```
//Employee class
int eid;
BigInteger eSalary;
String eName, eAddress;
```

Now I want to get all the objects in List who's Salary = 10000000

result should be :

[Employee [eid=1001, eName=Sam Smith, eAddress=Bangluru,    eSalary=10000000],     Employee [eid=1007, eName=Nag Gam,    eAddress=Pune, eSalary=10000000],  Employee [eid=1008, eName=Arti,    eAddress=Delhi, eSalary=10000000],.........................]

I would like to achieve this **without using any loop** or minimum loop required because **data will be large**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to avoid the loop using [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html).

First, consider using a generic collection:

```
List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>():
//add all employees to the list
```

Now you can use [streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) to filter your list

```
List<Employee> filtered = employees.stream()    
            .filter(emp -> emp.getSalary() == 10000000)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Edit: Probably Stream library is still using some kind of loop internally but while its implementation is hidden from me I do not worry.

Comment: Thanks your response  marcellorvalle. but I am using JAVA 1.6

Comment: I see. I think @JonasCz answer is th way to go. I think large number of employees is not a problem. Just for the sake of curiosity: is there any way to filter the data before populating the collection?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick; iterate over the List, and remove the items which you don't want, leaving only the ones which you *do* want.

```
List myList = new ArrayList(); //... add items

[...]

for (Iterator<Employee> iterator = myList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Employee e = iterator.next();
    if (e.getSalary() != 10000000) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}

//your list now contains only employees whose salary = 10000000
```

Edit: And no, you cannot do this without a loop. In order to do this kind of thing, you *have* to iterate over your Collection using a loop. Even if you use a library or the Java Streams API to do this, it will still use a loop of some sort under the hood. However, this will be quite efficient, even with as large dataset. (How large ? Why do you want to avoid using a loop ?)

Comment: data amount may be 100000

Comment: @Skyfall, That is nothing - a program can do that no problem is a few seconds, provided the data is not very complicated (and yours isn't).

Comment: @marcellorvalle, thanks for the edit ! I don't know how I missed that

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz

I am using your code like this:-

Comment: @Skyfall, If my answer helped you, you could mark it as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark next to it. Glad it helped :-)

Comment: Thanks @JonasCz. 
    empOne = [Employee [eid=1001, eName=Sam Smith, eAddress=Bangluru, eSalary=100000],  Employee [eid=1003, eName=Amt Lime, eAddress=G Bhagyoday, eSalary=200000], Employee [eid=1004, eName=Ash Wake, eAddress=BMC, eSalary=200000], Employee [eid=1005, eName=Will Smith, eAddress= Delhi, eSalary=200000], Employee [eid=1006, eName=Shya Ymwar, eAddress=Madras, eSalary=100000], Employee [eid=1007, eName=Nag Gam, eAddress=Pune, eSalary=50000], Employee [eid=1008, eName=Arti, eAddress=Delhi, eSalary=50000]]

Comment: empTwo = [Employee [eid=0, eName=null, eAddress=null, eSalary=100000], Employee [eid=0, eName=null, eAddress=null, eSalary=50000], Employee [eid=0, eName=null, eAddress=null, eSalary=200000]]
I am using your code like this:-
    for(Employee two : twoEmp){
         for (Iterator<Employee> iterator = oneEmp.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
      Employee e = iterator.next();
      if (e.geteSalary() != null && two.geteSalary() != null && e.geteSalary().compareTo(two.geteSalary()) == 0) {
          finalEmpList.add(e);
      }
         }
     }
But this still required 2 for loop

Comment: @Skyfall, Could you edit your question and add your code there ? Honestly, code in comments is not really readable. "But this still required 2 for loop", what do you mean with this ?

Answer (score 0):

A List is a sequential container, to do any kind of filtering on a list, your only option is to iterate over it.

For the query you mentioned,you can use the [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) data structure with a `BigInteger` type for the key (representing the salary) and a `List<Employee>` for the mapped value type. This will enable you to look for all the employees that earn a certain salary in constant time without having to iterate over the whole list.

Unfortunately though, this solution can't help you do any other queries like "how many employees earn more than 60000", to preform all types of queries on a large data set you should use a database.

PS: You don't need to use the `BigInteger` type for the salary, unless you think someone earns more than 2,147,483,647

Comment: Sir its an example... I want to applied something like this